# First img tag shows an image, second one which uses interpolation does not in Vue.js Front End

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have 2 `img` tags:

```
<img src="@/assets/img/profileicon/3867.png"/>
<img :src="'@/assets/img/profileicon/' + this.summonerInfo.profileIconId + '.png'">
```

this.summonerInfo.profileIconId stores the 3867 number which means both img tags should display the same image, however, the first one displays an image and the second one doesn't. When I inspect, the first img src leads to `"/img/3867.png"` and the second img src leads to `"@/assets/img/3867.png"`

From my root folder, the folder structure is like this:

```
src->assets->img->profileicon
```

Any idea why is the second img tag not displaying any image?

Comment: your string is not correct, try using backticks like this:   `\`@/assets/img/profileicon/${this.summonerInfo.profileIconId}.png`\`

Answer (score 3):

copy image to '/public/img' folder in root project

```
<img src="/img/profileicon/3867.png"/>
```